# Gitlab - jest test - Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: npm, jestjs, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, ts-jest

In the GitLab Runner,
After all the npm modules are installed,
Jest is ran for all the unit tests that are in Typescript.

The Jest Command is:

```
jest ./API/* --verbose --coverage --detectOpenHandles --bail --ci
```

This is the error:

```
Test Suites: 6 passed, 6 total
Tests:       10 passed, 10 total
Snapshots:   1 passed, 1 total
Time:        22.953 s
Ran all test suites matching ./API/**.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Cleaning up file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Thats the end of the script, So the tests pass, but then it fails afterwards because of the `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Just before the test start, the memory is this:

```
MEMORY UPDATE
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3693         519         338         199        2836        2695
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay          22G  6.9G   15G  33% /
CPU(s):              1
```

How would I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Jest, if you use `--detectOpenHandles` it will try to look up open handles that gitlab doesn't allow you to.

When you are running Jest. Just make sure you don't use this flag and they should work!